# Logging execution time of sql statements inside certain methods only

Tags: java, spring, performance, aop

I need to log SQL statements execution time, but I need to do that for certain flows only, for instance suppose I have a method that have multiple  sql statements, and I need only to log the execution time of the following statements on the following method only.

I'm doing the following in order to log execution time of all sql statements, but this is, I think a bad practice since it could impact application performance.

```
@Around("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate..*(String, ..)) "
        + " || execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate..*(String, ..))")
public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final Object obj = pjp.proceed();
    final long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    final String statement = pjp.getArgs()[0].toString();
    SqlTiming sqlTiming;
    synchronized(sqlTimings) {
        sqlTiming = sqlTimings.get(statement);
        if (sqlTiming == null) {
            sqlTiming = new SqlTiming(statement);
            sqlTimings.put(statement, sqlTiming);
        }
    }
    sqlTiming.recordTiming(time);
    LOGGER.perf().info("Sql: {}, {}, time: {} ms", pjp.getSignature().getName(), statement, time);

    return obj;
}
```

My question is how can I log sql execution time in certain methods/flows only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to limit pointcuts to a certain execution flow - called "control flow" in AspectJ terms - you need the corresponding pointcuts `cflow()` or `cflowbelow()`. But if you use Spring AOP, you cannot use them as the [manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators) explains.

Consequently, you need to switch to [AspectJ via LTW (load-time weaving)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ataspectj), unless you want to go looking into callstacks at runtime. But of course the control flow pointcuts are also evaluated during runtime because control flow is dynamic. It should still be a lot faster than doing it manually.

An alternative is to refactor your code to route the calls of interest through a certain facade method while others go somewhere else. Then you can easily write a Spring AOP pointcut.

Many ways lead to Rome, as they say - or to Jerusalem.